# People can't hear me after about 5 minutes on my iphone6

Tags: iphone, call

After 5 to 10 minutes into a phone call the person I am talking to can no longer hear me but I can still hear them. I call back and it works fine for a few minutes. In every other respect the phone seems to work fine. This problem occurs for all calls and makes no difference whether I call them on my iPhone or they call me. I do not use Bluetooth. It has IOS 12.4.5, I think it's up to date.

Comment: What's your iOS version? Do you use your phone or a Bluetooth device? Is your connection good?

Comment: Who has the iPhone?  You or the other party?  Is it with one particular party or with all parties?

Comment: IOS 12.4.5   It's my iphone6 and it happens all the time regardless who I am talking to or who made the call initially.

Comment: The connection is usually good. I do not use Bluetooth.

Comment: How long has this been an  issue?

Comment: About two years.

Comment: Is it possible you’re inadvertently hitting the mute button? What does your signal strength look like? Have you tried resetting the phone (make a back up first)?

Comment: As this problem repeated i became very careful how i handle the phone so I'm quite sure I'm not hitting the mute button. Signal strength is generally good. I haven't tried a reset, a little worried what I might lose but may have to.  Thanks

Comment: This has been a problem for about 2 years. I have had the phone for about 3 years.

Comment: Did a reset and now seems to be working.  Thanks